# OIDC authentication from inside an iframe in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, openid-connect

My company use a CRM to manage customer relationship.
I have the ability to add a custom webpage in it through an "embed" feature.
As a consequence, my webpage appear in an iframe and I only control the src url of this iframe.

Then, I want to set-up an authentication flow in my webpage using OIDC.
But I don't manage to make it work in the iframe.

Do you know whereas it is possible or not, and if yes, how to make it work ?
Thanks a lot

This authentication flow works well outside of the iframe, using for example oidc-react or oidc-client-ts.
I've tested to use a popup without success.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OAuth logins in an iframe for a third party domain won't work, due to third party cookie restrictions introduced a few years ago in browsers, and explained in the [RFC6265bis](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-rfc6265bis/#name-same-site-and-cross-site-re) document.

A code flow starts with parameters like this:

```
GET https://login.example.com/oauth/v2/authorize?
client_id=myclient&
redirect_uri=http://www.product.com/callback&
response_type=code&
scope=openid&
code_challenge=WhmRaP18B9z2zkYcIlb4uVcZzjLqcZsaBQJf5akUxsA&
code_challenge_method=S256&
state=CfDJ8Nxa-YhPzjpBilDQz2C
```

The authorization server validates received parameters. Then redirects to a URL like this, while setting a cookie to secure all subsequent requests used for user authentication:

```
GET https://login.example.com/authentication/form
```

On the second request the cookie will not be resent, even if the authorization server uses `SameSite=none, Secure, HttpOnly` cookie properties. Exact behaviour may vary across browsers. Safari is a good one to test with since it is very strict.

OAuth logins on an iframe are also bad from a user privacy viewpoint, since the user does not see the usual HTTPS browser bar, to inform them who they are providing credentials to.

Therefore, always use the main window for OAuth logins. Browsers then allow `SameSite=none` cookies issued by the authorization server to stick, so that logins are reliable

Finally, many login pages will refuse to render in an iframe due to risks such as [clickjacking](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options).

Using third party iframes these days tends to restrict your options. Therefore, many organization these days consider alternative designs, that eliminate the need for third party iframes.